# Make page number landscape while using sidewaystable

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing a document which I have tried to use sidewaystable to rotate the table. The challenge is that it is required that the the page number is rotated as shown in the picture. How can I achieve this. MWE is provided below

[image: Example]

`````
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}



\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    %\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    %   \centering
    \small
    \caption{Key aspects.}
    \label{td_ra}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \cline{2-12}
        \multirow{2}{*}{}                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Aspect} & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{References}   \\ \cline{3-12} 
        &                   &    &    &    &  &  &  && &  &       \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Opt}}}  & Optimal devices      &   &   &   & & & &  & & &   \\\cline{2-12}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                       & Machine optimization         &  &  &   & & && & &  &        \\ \hline
        
        
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document} ````
`````

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I also have the same question but no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution as following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everypage,graphicx}
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}


\begin{document}
   \clearpage % Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty} % empty page style (?)
    \atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in}{.5\paperheight}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{\thepage}}

    \begin{sidewaystable} % <-- HERE
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            A & B & C & D \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption} 
    \end{sidewaystable} % <-- HERE

\clearpage % Flush page


\end{document}
```

Hope this works for you too.